# how to rewrite the url using HTACCESS?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My HTACCESS file working perfectly on my local server, but its not work in my sever.

in my HTACCESS File

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^index/?$   http://www.vividkerala.com/index.php  [NC]
```

its just redirect instead of rewrite.

did i make any mistake? pls help me..